# RuntimeError: new_Ad returned -1

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -adcdev plughw:1,0 -inmic yes -dict 4711.dic -lm 4711.lm
```

The above command works but the problem arises in running python code.

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech
for phrase in LiveSpeech(): print(phrase)
```

the error that is displayed

```
Error opening audio device (null) for capture: Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.ad = Ad(self.audio_device, self.sampling_rate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinxbase/ad_pulse.py", line 124, in __init__
    this = _ad_pulse.new_Ad(audio_device, sampling_rate)
RuntimeError: new_Ad returned -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably experiencing it with USB microphone (e. g. on RaspberryPi). It tells you, that 
LiveSpeech doesn't know, which audio device to use for input.
Luckily according to https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python#default-config there are several configuration options - so you need to specify audio_device.

basically lets do:

```
for phrase in LiveSpeech(audio_device=3): print(phrase)
```

where 3 please replace with your desired microphone ID. Now how to get it:

```
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    print(p.get_device_info_by_index(i))
#otherwise you can do:
print(p.get_default_input_device_info())
```

There are several topics on how to properly set up USB microphone on RaspberryPi - if its your case, let me know.

Comment: looking like audio device must be name, because if prvode number:
in method 'new_Ad', argument 1 of type 'char const *'