# pocketsphinx - Not running

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I installed pocketsphinx using pip command

pip install  pocketsphinx

i referred the link  [pocketsphinx installation](https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python)

then i add a test.py and add code like this

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech


for phrase in LiveSpeech():
    print(phrase)
```

then i run my file using python test.py command

but showing error

```
    for phrase in LiveSpeech():
  File "/home/pi/Sphinix/newvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.ad = Ad(self.audio_device, self.sampling_rate)
  File "/home/pi/Sphinix/newvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/ad_pulse.py", line 122, in __init__
    this = _ad_pulse.new_Ad(audio_device, sampling_rate)
RuntimeError: new_Ad returned -1
```

i tried

```
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    print(p.get_device_info_by_index(i))
```

i got the result

```
{'index': 0, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'USB PnP Sound Device: Audio (hw:2,0)', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 1, 'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.008684807256235827, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.034829931972789115, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
{'index': 1, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'dmix', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 0, 'maxOutputChannels': 2, 'defaultLowInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultHighInputLatency': -1.0, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.021333333333333333, 'defaultSampleRate': 48000.0}
```

then i tried

```
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech
    

    for phrase in LiveSpeech(audio_device=1):
        print(phrase)
```

again showing

```
   for phrase in LiveSpeech(audio_device=1):
  File "/home/pi/Sphinix/newvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/__init__.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.ad = Ad(self.audio_device, self.sampling_rate)
  File "/home/pi/Sphinix/newvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinxbase/ad_pulse.py", line 122, in __init__
    this = _ad_pulse.new_Ad(audio_device, sampling_rate)
TypeError: in method 'new_Ad', argument 1 of type 'char const *'
```

How can i fix this..  ?

Comment: You can try to add sampling_rate=44100 and properly select the device with audio_device=1,2,3 as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780090/python-livespeech-pocketsphinx

Comment: hi @Nikolay Shmyrev 
i added audio_device and sampling rate.. but also showing Error

 for phrase in LiveSpeech(audio_device=3, sampling_rate=44100):
      print(phrase)

but shoiwng error

Comment: @David Bouška  


I tried adding audio_device but also showing the error
can anyone help me

Comment: @Nikolay Shmyrev

I tried adding audio_device but also showing the error can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

Let us see your output:
If everything works your output should be
list of phrases which you speak in text for your  code above
But throws an error. This is a clear indication that your LiveSpeech recognizer did not recognize. In order for this to work your LiveSpeech requires a MIC.in your case, It is clear that your audio device is being used by other processes. You can identify which service is using your audio device and terminate its process to release the audio device so that your code can use it.

You can use this command to find the process:

```
lsof /dev/snd/*
```

Once you release the sound card from the process using it, you should be able to run the code.